# Golang encode string UTF16 little endian and hash with MD5

Tags: hash, go, md5

I am a Go beginner and stuck with a problem.
I want to encode a string with UTF16 little endian and then hash it with MD5 (hexadecimal). I have found a piece of Python code, which does exactly what I want. But I am not able to transfer it to Google Go.

```
md5 = hashlib.md5()
md5.update(challenge.encode('utf-16le'))
response = md5.hexdigest()
```

The challenge is a variable containing a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with less work (or at least more understandability, IMO) by using [golang.org/x/text/encoding](http://golang.org/x/text/encoding) and [golang.org/x/text/transform](http://golang.org/x/text/transform) to create a Writer chain that will do the encoding and hashing without so much manual byte slice handling. The equivalent function:

```
func utf16leMd5(s string) []byte {
    enc := unicode.UTF16(unicode.LittleEndian, unicode.IgnoreBOM).NewEncoder()
    hasher := md5.New()
    t := transform.NewWriter(hasher, enc)
    t.Write([]byte(s))
    return hasher.Sum(nil)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`unicode/utf16`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/) package for UTF-16 encoding. [`utf16.Encode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/#Encode) returns the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode code point sequence (slice of runes: `[]rune`). You can simply convert a `string` to a slice of runes, e.g. `[]rune("some string")`, and you can easily produce the byte sequence of the little-endian encoding by ranging over the `uint16` codes and sending/appending first the low byte then the high byte to the output (this is what Little Endian means).

For Little Endian encoding, alternatively you can use the [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package: it has an exported `LittleEndian` variable and it has a `PutUint16()` method.

As for the MD5 checksum, the [`crypto/md5`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/) package has what you want, [`md5.Sum()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/#Sum) simply returns the MD5 checksum of the byte slice passed to it.

Here's a little function that captures what you want to do:

```
func utf16leMd5(s string) [16]byte {
    codes := utf16.Encode([]rune(s))
    b := make([]byte, len(codes)*2)
    for i, r := range codes {
        b[i*2] = byte(r)
        b[i*2+1] = byte(r >> 8)
    }
    return md5.Sum(b)
}
```

Using it:

```
s := "Hello, playground"
fmt.Printf("%x\n", utf16leMd5(s))

s = "エヌガミ"
fmt.Printf("%x\n", utf16leMd5(s))
```

Output:

```
8f4a54c6ac7b88936e990256cc9d335b
5f0db9e9859fd27f750eb1a212ad6212
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/KprUniZXjv).

The variant that uses `encoding/binary` would look like this:

```
for i, r := range codes {
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(b[i*2:], r)
}
```

(Although this is slower as it creates lots of new slice headers.)

Answer (score 2):

So, for reference, I used this complete python program:

```py
import hashlib
import codecs

md5 = hashlib.md5()
md5.update(codecs.encode('Hello, playground', 'utf-16le'))
response = md5.hexdigest()
print response
```

It prints `8f4a54c6ac7b88936e990256cc9d335b`

Here is the Go equivalent: https://play.golang.org/p/Nbzz1dCSGI

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/binary"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf16"
)

func main() {
    s := "Hello, playground"

    fmt.Println(md5Utf16le(s))
}

func md5Utf16le(s string) string {
    encoded := utf16.Encode([]rune(s))

    b := convertUTF16ToLittleEndianBytes(encoded)

    return md5Hexadecimal(b)
}

func md5Hexadecimal(b []byte) string {
    h := md5.New()
    h.Write(b)
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}

func convertUTF16ToLittleEndianBytes(u []uint16) []byte {
    b := make([]byte, 2*len(u))
    for index, value := range u {
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(b[index*2:], value)
    }
    return b
}
```