# Converting C# SHA1 code to Golang

Tags: c#, go, sha1

I need to convert some old C# code to Golang and I stuck somewhere. C# code looks like this 
`

```
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
 byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);
 byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
 Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
 Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
 HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
 byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
 return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
```

so I examined the code line by line and as I understand he used convert the salt and password byte array then he copied these arrays to 'dst' array. Then he used SHA1 algorithm and convert this array to base64string.

My Golang code looks like this but It doesn't create the same string which stores on database.

```
s := "fish123"
salt := "227EA7ABD26E40608A6EDEB209058D93A632D1D1A52246D0A27F6E447B16AEBF"

h1 := sha1.New()
h1.Write([]byte(salt))
h1.Write([]byte(s))

hashedPassword := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h1.Sum(nil))
```

Can anyone find my fault? Thanks

Comment: I don't know Golang, but first thing I noticed is that he is using `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes`, which means it will produce 2 bytes per character in the `bytes` and `src` array, and subsequently `dst` array. Can you check for your Golang code that it handles this correctly?

Comment: @icza I don't understand why salt need to be interpreted as a hex string? In database it saved as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the C# code is using the `Encoding.Unicode`. In Go it should be:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf16"
)

func main() {
    s := "fish123"
    salt := "227EA7ABD26E40608A6EDEB209058D93A632D1D1A52246D0A27F6E447B16AEBF"

    h1 := sha1.New()
    h1.Write(convertUTF16ToLittleEndianBytes(salt))
    h1.Write(convertUTF16ToLittleEndianBytes(s))

    b64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h1.Sum(nil))
    fmt.Println(b64)
}

func convertUTF16ToLittleEndianBytes(s string) []byte {
    u := utf16.Encode([]rune(s))
    b := make([]byte, 2*len(u))
    for index, value := range u {
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(b[index*2:], value)
    }
    return b
}
```

The [`convertUTF16ToLittleEndianBytes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33711331/613130) was taken from another response on SO.

Comment: works like charm! thank you man I've been struggling with this for 2 days